# Create an archive with current date and time in file name using 7z command line

Tags: windows, compression, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, 7zip

Today I lost my whole Far Cry 3 save game suddenly. So now I want to backup it's save game folder automatically on a certain period of time using windows task scheduling.

I want to include date and time in archive file name.

Here is my command

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r "D:\FC3\%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4% %TIME% Backup".7z  "C:\ProgramData\Orbit\46"
```

For formatting purpose, I followed [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/206817)

I am getting log when executing this command

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive D:\FC3\24.02.2013 17:52:10.62 Backup.7z

Error:
7-Zip cannot open file
D:\FC3\24.02.2013 17:52:10.62 Backup.7z
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

System error: Unspecified error
```

If I use a simple file name like "D:\abc". It would work.

Please help. Where I am going wrong..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the point

File Names can not have `:`

I fixed the code by replacing colon with `.`

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r "D:\FC3\%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4% %TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~-5% Backup".7z  "C:\ProgramData\Orbit\46"
```

Comment: not working on windows, its creating folders from data parts